# Debug.print statement causes a System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a VB.net application and in the form load I have a simple `debug.print` statement as per below:

```
Debug.Print("Application Started " & Format(Date.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
```

The application was running fine and I didn't have any errors but then I did something and I started getting an error.  The last thing I did before noticing the error was I did a search and replace of a variable name `start` and I renamed this to `startSearchIdx` and I think it replaced text in my `form1.designer.vb`code as I had to back out this change.

First this error only occurs on this current project. If I create a new VB.net windows form project with a button and this code then all is good, so it must be a setting or something in a configuration file which is causing the error?

When I run the application in debug mode, the application stops on the `DEBUG.PRINT` line as per the below image and I also receive the message:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll"

in the Immediate window. However if press <kbd>F5</kbd> and continue then the application starts, and I see:

> Application Started 16-Oct-2019 04:55:24 PM"

in the debug window.

The application then runs fine and any future `debug.print` statement appears to work in other code locations? I am hoping someone may be able to provide some light on this strange error?

Image of the VB IDE debug.print Configuration Error:

[image]

Comment: Try commenting out all the code in Form_Load except the Debug.Print line

Comment: The exception is generated elsewhere. Back-track and see what may be failing, when the `ConfigurationManager` is used, possibly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I commented out everything bar the debug print statement and it still caused the error.   When I backtrack, press F8 two variables are initialised and then then form_load is called which produces the error.

Comment: Ok I found the error - it was in my App.config file which had the following:   

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startSearchIdxup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startSearchIdxup>
</configuration>

This issue was due to that search and replace i did and as a result the <startup> was changed to  <startSearchIdxup>.